# Synchronous alternative for setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know setState is asynchronous and it may not mutate the state immediately after calling setState(), is there any alternative method for changing the state synchronously or immediately mutating the state ?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, so if you would say what you want to do, what you have tried, and what your ideal outcome would be, maybe other suggestions can follow. As your question is now, Quentins answer is accurate, albeit maybe premature depending on an extended question

Comment: You can use this.forceUpdate() before whatever is using state if you need to be sure your state updated. However, this is usually a React antipattern and it's better to approach the problem differently and use a different abstraction.

Comment: " is there any alternative method for changing the state synchronously or immediately mutating the state ?" no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no synchronous alternative to [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Depending on your use-case you can use `setState` directly to work around common pitfalls.

If you want a counter (or something similar to one), you can achieve serialized state updates by passing a function to `setState`:

```
foo() {
  this.setState(state => {
    return {counter: state.counter + 1};
  });
}
```

the function will get `state` (and optionally also `props`) as parameters and you can return an object that will be used to update the state.

This will prevent the missed updates you would get when using something like:

```
this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1})
```

If you want to know when the state update has finished, you can use the optional second argument to `setState`:

```
this.setState({foo: 12}, () => {
  // Do something after the state updated...
});
```

You can also mix both variants if needed (pass 2 funtions to setState)

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. Anyway, if you want the state to act synchronously because you want to trigger a function right after the update, there is a way to know if the state changed or not, so that you can call functions sequentially:

```
setState({/*state values*/}, () => {/*function triggered*/})
```

Answer (score 1):

No. setState is asynchronous full stop.